# Grad school GPA and Phd

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, grades

How much can your grad school GPA affect your chances of getting into a Phd Program?

Some of my teachers suggested that your motivation to be a researcher is what matters the most, but i am still not ready to buy in on that and would it be an advantage if you have a masters which focuses more on research ?

P.S Sociology major

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see how a GPA from an MS program would affect your chances at all. I can see how an undergrad GPA might affect your chances of getting into grad school ever so slightly, because it's one of the few pieces of evidence an admissions committee gets. But after an MS presumably you have other evidence (research work, projects) to demonstrate your capability for a Ph.D

Comment: I did good during my undergrad, but for my Masters i had some issues settling into a completely new academic and cultural setting which affected my performance. Thank you for your response